# Optimisation Multiple Constraints - Using CVXOPT

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, linear-algebra, cvxopt

I am trying to solve a linear algebra problem: an optimisation problem and I am using CVXOPT. I've split the problem into 3 components

In its simplest form, The general formulation for CVXOPT is

Minimize 1/2xTPx+qTx

subject to Gx≤h

and Ax=b.

**1st problem component**
First of all I have to minimize, subject to constraint a very simple problem defined as following

P=

```
|   S   |
```

q=

```
|   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   |
```

b=

```
|   1   |
```

G=

```
|   r   |
|   -I  |
```

h=

```
|   rmin    0   |
```

I have coded this and it is working perfectly

**2nd problem component**
The second problem I have is to transform a non convex problem into convex and linear so that the turnover generated by the optimisation problem it is constrained to a max value. In this case I have modelled and coded the problem as following and again all works fine

P=

```
  | S   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
  | 0   0   0   |
```

q=

```
|   -x1 0   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   0   0   |
|   I   I   -I  |
```

b=

```
|   1   x0  0   |
```

G=

```
|   0   1   1   |
|   -I  0   0   |
|   0   -I  0   |
|   0   0   -I  |
```

h=

```
|   T   0   0   |
```

**3rd problem component**
The third problem which I am struggling with (to solve) is to combine the two above. What I have done, which is obviously not correct as it turns to be a singular matrix is doing the following

P=

```
|   S   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
|   0   0   0   |
```

q=

```
|   -x1 0   0   |
```

A=

```
|   1   0   0   |
|   I   I   -I  |
```

b=

```
|   1   x0  0   |
```

G=

```
|   0   1   1       |
|   -I  0   0       |
|   0   -I  0       |
|   0   0   -I      |
|   0   0   rmin    |
|   0   0   -I      |
```

h=

```
|   T   0   0   rmin    0   |
```

As I think The problem of the singularity comes from G, can anyone help me formulating the third problem in a correct way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add another column to your G matrix

```
|0    |
|0    |
|0    |
|rmin |
|-I   |
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a go and let you know